# Bring down third table

Tags: tables

I have the following table that fits in a page, unfortunately

(1) I have no idea how to bring down the third table so that I will have 2 table at the top and 2 table at the bottom

(2) Also, how to place  a gap between 2 top table and 2 bottom table?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  $k$ & $w_k +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ & $\bigg(\dfrac{w_k}{5}\bigg)$ \\ 
  \hline
  $1$ & $ 1+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$ \\
  \hline 
  $2$ & $ 1+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $3$ & $ 1+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $4$ & $ 4+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $5$ & $ 3+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $6$ & $ 2+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $7$ & $ 1+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $8$ & $ 1+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $9$ & $ 1+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $10$ & $ 2+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $11$ & $ 4+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $12$ & $ 2+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $13$ & $ 1+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $14$ & $ 4+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $15$ & $ 3+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $16$ & $4+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $17$ & $ 4+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $18$ & $ 3+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $19$ & $ 4+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $20$ & $ 2+5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $21$ & $4+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $22$ & $4+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $23$ & $4+ 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $24$ & $2+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $25$ & $3+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $26$ & $1+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $27$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $28$ & $ 1+5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $29$ & $1+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $30$ & $1+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill % Second tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  $k$ & $w_k +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$\bigg(\dfrac{w_k}{5}\bigg)$ \\
  \hline
  $31$ & $ 4+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $32$ & $ 4+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $33$ & $1+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $34$ & $4+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $35$ & $2 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $36$ & $3+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $37$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $38$ & $1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $39$ & $1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $40$ & $3 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $41$ & $ 1+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $42$ & $2+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $43$ & $ 1+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $44$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $45$ & $ 2+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $46$ & $1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $47$ & $ 4+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $48$ & $ 3+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $49$ & $1 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $50$ & $ 3+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $51$ & $1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $52$ & $4+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $53$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $54$ & $ 3+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $55$ & $2+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $56$ & $ 1+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $57$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $58$ & $ 1+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $59$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $60$ & $ 4+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill% Third tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  $k$ & $w_k +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$\bigg(\dfrac{w_k}{5}\bigg)$\\
  \hline
  $61$ & $4+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $62$ & $4+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $63$ & $ 4+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $64$ & $1+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $65$ & $ 2+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $66$ & $ 3+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $67$ & $4+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $68$ & $4+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $69$ & $4+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $70$ & $3+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $71$ & $ 1+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $72$ & $3 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $73$ & $ 4+5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $74$ & $1+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $75$ & $ 2+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $76$ & $ 1+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $77$ & $1+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $78$ & $ 2+4\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $79$ & $1+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $80$ & $3+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $81$ & $ 1+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $82$ & $ 1+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $83$ & $ 1+5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $84$ & $3 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $85$ & $ 2+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $86$ & $ 4+2\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $87$ & $1 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $88$ & $ 4+3\cdot 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $89$ & $4+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $90$ & $4+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill% Fourth tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  $k$ & $w_k +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$\bigg(\dfrac{w_k}{5}\bigg)$\\
  \hline
  $91$ & $1+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $92$ & $1+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $93$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $94$ & $1+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $95$ & $3+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $96$ & $2+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $97$ & $1+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $98$ & $4+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $99$ & $4+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $100$ & $2 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $101$ & $4+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $102$ & $3+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $103$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $104$ & $1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $105$ & $3 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $106$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $107$ & $1+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $108$ & $2+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $109$ & $4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $110$ & $2+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $111$ & $4+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $112$ & $1+ 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $113$ & $1+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $114$ & $2+ 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $115$ & $3+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$-1$\\
  \hline
  $116$ & $4+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $117$ & $1+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $118$ & $4+4\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $119$ & $1+2\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
  $120$ & $1+3\cdot 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2)$ &$1$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\captionof{table}{$w_k$ for $k=1, \cdots, 120$} \label{table:wn2seriess} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which looks like this :
[image]

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I try compiling your code, I get the table nicely distributed in a 2 by 2 format as you ask. So, are you sure the output figure you showed in your question is the result from your MWE?

Comment: You could replace `\hfill` with `\vspace*{\fill}` between the 2nd and the 3rd table, . In any case, the whole table won't fit in a page. I suggest you to split it into two subtables.

Answer (score 2):

Your table is to big to be fit into one page. You have more possibilities to solve your problem:

- Split table in two parts and for numbering use `\ContinuedFloat`
- Enlarge text width of document.  For example with `\usepackage[margin=35mm]{geometry}` in pdocument preamble you will get enough space for all four tables in one row (if in the same time you reduce `\tabcolsep` to 3pt and reduce space around `\cdot`):

[image]

- enlarge text width only in table, for examply with macro `adjustwidth` from package `changepage`

Off-topic: you can with definition of column type as `\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}` delete all others `$` in table as it is done in MWE below, which consider second case of listed possibilities:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, tabularx, caption}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\scriptsize}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
%\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
  \hline
\thead{k} 
    & \thead{w_k +\mathcal{O}(5^2)} & \thead{\left(\dfrac{w_k}{5}\right)} \\
  \hline
  1 &  1+\mathcal{O}(5^2)           &1 \\
  \hline
  2 &  1+\mathcal{O}(5^2)           &1\\
  \hline
  3 &  1+\mathcal{O}(5^2)           &1\\
  \hline
  4 &  4+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  5 &  3+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  6 &  2+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  7 &  1+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  8 &  1+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  9 &  1+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  10 &  2+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  11 &  4+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  12 &  2+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  13 &  1+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  14 &  4+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  15 &  3+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  16 & 4+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  17 &  4+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  18 &  3+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  19 &  4+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  20 &  2+5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  21 & 4+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  22 & 4+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  23 & 4+ 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  24 & 2+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  25 & 3+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  26 & 1+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  27 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  28 &  1+5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  29 & 1+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  30 & 1+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill % Second tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
  \hline
\thead{k}
    & \thead{w_k +\mathcal{O}(5^2)} & \thead{\left(\dfrac{w_k}{5}\right)} \\
  \hline
  31 &  4+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  32 &  4+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  33 & 1+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  34 & 4+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  35 & 2 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  36 & 3+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  37 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  38 & 1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  39 & 1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  40 & 3 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  41 &  1+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  42 & 2+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  43 &  1+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  44 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  45 &  2+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  46 & 1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  47 &  4+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  48 &  3+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  49 & 1 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  50 &  3+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  51 & 1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  52 & 4+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  53 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  54 &  3+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  55 & 2+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  56 &  1+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  57 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  58 &  1+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  59 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  60 &  4+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill% Third tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
  \hline
\thead{k}
    & \thead{w_k +\mathcal{O}(5^2)} & \thead{\left(\dfrac{w_k}{5}\right)} \\
  \hline
  61 & 4+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  62 & 4+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  63 &  4+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  64 & 1+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  65 &  2+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  66 &  3+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  67 & 4+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  68 & 4+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  69 & 4+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  70 & 3+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  71 &  1+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  72 & 3 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  73 &  4+5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  74 & 1+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  75 &  2+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  76 &  1+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  77 & 1+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  78 &  2+4{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  79 & 1+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  80 & 3+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  81 &  1+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  82 &  1+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  83 &  1+5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  84 & 3 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  85 &  2+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  86 &  4+2{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  87 & 1 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  88 &  4+3{\cdot} 5+\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  89 & 4+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  90 & 4+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill% Fourth tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
  \hline
\thead{k}
    & \thead{w_k +\mathcal{O}(5^2)} & \thead{\left(\dfrac{w_k}{5}\right)} \\
  \hline
  91 & 1+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  92 & 1+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  93 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  94 & 1+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  95 & 3+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  96 & 2+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  97 & 1+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  98 & 4+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  99 & 4+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  100 & 2 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  101 & 4+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  102 & 3+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  103 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  104 & 1+5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  105 & 3 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  106 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  107 & 1+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  108 & 2+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  109 & 4 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  110 & 2+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  111 & 4+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  112 & 1+ 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  113 & 1+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  114 & 2+ 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  115 & 3+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &-1\\
  \hline
  116 & 4+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  117 & 1+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  118 & 4+4{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  119 & 1+2{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
  120 & 1+3{\cdot} 5 +\mathcal{O}(5^2) &1\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{$w_k$ for $k=1, \cdots, 120$} \label{table:wn2seriess}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For the first case the (shortened) MWE is:

```
...
\begin{table}% first table
\centering
% first tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
...
% second tabular
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
...
\end{tabular}
\caption{...}
\end{table}

\begin{table}% second table
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
% third tabular
\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
...
% fourth tabular
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{>{$}c<{$}|}}
...
\end{tabular}
\caption{...}% it has the same number as the first (part of) table
\end{table}
```

And for the last case (result is the same as shown in above image):

```
% preamble
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

...
\begin{table}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\marginparwidth}% for case of two side document
...
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}
...
```